# Consuming VB.NET Web Service with Legacy ColdFusion 4.5

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wddx

My legacy ColdFusion 4.5 app needs to consume a VB.NET web service and I am wondering if anyone has had success deserializing XML using the ColdFusion CFWDDX ACTION="WDDX2CFML"

I have not had success yet and would appreciate any code examples as I cannot use CFINVOKE.

Comment: More info needed. Please take a moment and talk about what you are currently doing, provide some code snippets, and show any error messages or strange behavior you experience when attempting to consume said service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to Serialize your VB.Net data?  If you haven't found a decent means of doing that, then this library: http://boncode.blogspot.com/2011/10/net-wddxnet-library-revision.html looks to be a good one for doing so.  You should be able to deserialize well formed WDDX back into CF code with the `<cfwddx action="WDDX2CFML">`, as you mentioned.  If you have some WDDX values that are not being correctly brought over with that tag, then please post that WDDX so we can see what might be causing the problem.